# Split the kendo scheduler occurrence

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Created occurrence from Day1 to Day3. Now, I need to split the occurrence like Day1, Day2 and Day3 separately using occurrence CLONE in kendo scheduler.

How to split the events?

```
  var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
    var originalEvent = occurance;

   var clone = occurance.clone({
        start: new Date("2013/6/4 00:01"), //occurance.start, //new Date("2013/6/4 00:01"),
        end: new Date("2013/6/4 20:50"),
        title: "sella"
    });
    scheduler.dataSource.add(clone);

    var clone1 = occurance.clone({
        start: new Date("2013/6/5 00:01"),
        end: new Date("2013/6/5 23:50"),
        title: "sella222"
    });
    scheduler.dataSource.add(clone1);

    var clone2 = occurance.clone({
        start: new Date("2013/6/7 00:01"),
        end: new Date("2013/6/7 23:50"),
        title: "sellasfgsg5323"
    });
    scheduler.dataSource.add(clone2);

    //ToDo: remove just the single occurance of the event based on its target and uid
    scheduler.dataSource.remove(originalEvent);
    originalEvent.update(clone);
    originalEvent.update(clone1);
    originalEvent.update(clone2);

    scheduler.dataSource.sync();
```

Now, clone , clone1, clone2 is not updating in scheduler grid.